# google cloud dataflow mysql io connector using python

Tags: python, mysql, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-sql, apache-beam-io

what is the efficient way to insert streaming records into MySQL from google-dataflow using python.Is there any IO connector as in case of bigquery?I see that or bigquery  has beam.io.WriteToBigQuery. how can we use similar io connector in cloud-MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you `JDBCIO` to read and write data from/to a JDBC database compliant database.

You can find the details here [testWrite](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/jdbc/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/JdbcIOTest.java#L415)

Comment: It seems like this is only for the Java SDK ? Do you know of any solution using the python SDK ?